# after upgrading from 1.4.1 to 1.9 navigation menu doesn't show anymore

Tags: upgrade, navigation, menu, magento-1.9

I'm updating an old magento install and I just upgraded it from

```
1.4.1 (to 1.4.2 first) to 1.9.
```

Now the top navigation menu doesn't show anymore. The category structure is still intact. I've tried several tutorials online on how to display the top navigation menu, but none worked so far.

I'm following this tutorial..http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/navigation/add_home_link_to_menu_bar

I'm looking inside

```
app/design/frontend/default/yourtheme/template/catalog/navigation/top.phtml
```

But the file isn't being parsed, I can put nonsense php statements inside it and don't get any error messages on the site. I've disabled compilation and all cache on the site.

How can I get this working? Or normally where is this file called from?

**Edit1:** I see now that in

```
app/design/frontend/default/yourtheme/template/page/html/header.phtml
```

the top menu is called..

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topMenu') ?>
```

But this string is empty. I've added `topmenu.phtml` to

```
app/design/frontend/default/yourtheme/template/page/html/
```

This file isn't called as well. I don't know why this isn't working, any advice is welcome.

**Edit2**

The content of `top.menu` is empty, I'd like to get this fixed first. I've tried to call it in several ways..

```
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('top.menu')->toHtml()
```

or

```
$layout = Mage::app()->getLayout();
$layout->getUpdate()
        ->addHandle('default')
        ->load();

$layout->generateXml()
        ->generateBlocks();

var_dump( $layout->getBlock('top.menu')->toHtml());
```

**Edit3**

I wanted to know where the `top.menu` is filled, I've found two files

```
   app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Topmenu.php   
   app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/TopMenu/Renderer.php
```

The functions in both classes aren't called, even though I'm using

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topMenu') ?>
```

in a file that gets parsed. So I'm wondering am I calling the right method to  display the top menu? Or am I looking at the wrong files?

Comment: Try checking out `app/design/frontend/default/yourtheme/template/page/html/topmenu.phtml` instead. Is your theme using that one instead?

Comment: That file isn't present in the template, is there any other file I could check?

Comment: Move it from the base (`app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/html/topmenu.phtml`) into your theme (`app/design/frontend/default/yourtheme/template/page/html/topmenu.phtml`) and then see if it is using it.

Comment: Also see my edited main response. I've deleted the topmenu.phtml from base and added a topmenu.phtml to the template. But this file isn't parsed.

Comment: Turn on [template path hints](http://www.pauldonnelly.net/magento-turning-on-template-path-hints/) in your admin to see what file is being loaded to display your navigation menu.

Comment: Thanks, that's a very useful tool. The top.menu isn't loaded on the page. I've looked at the contents and it is empty (see edit2 of the original post). I've asked another question in the edit3 section of my original post, could you look into that as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a lot of searching I found out that my template missed the reference to top.menu. So I copied catalog.xml from  app/design/frontend/default/default/layout to design/frontend/default/mytemplate/layout

```
      <reference name="top.menu">
        <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.topnav" template="catalog/navigation/top.phtml"/>
    </reference>
```